# JNA: Missing some specifics methods

Tags: java, jna

I'm wanting create a dll injector in Java ( and only in Java ) for educational proporses for myself and found a basic example in a [website especialized in online game](http://www.gamekiller.net/threads/new-casma-injector-v0-2-java-source-and-were-back-to-business.163959/).

The autor only said that was made using JNA interface.

So, i'm studyng this piece of code and trying compile with success using NetBeans IDE and JNA, but seem that JNA interface that i have here ( 4.2.2 ) not have all methods and functions used on piece of code left by autor.

Are they:

1. **GetProcAddress**
2. **VirtualAllocEx**
3. **VirtualFreeEx**

So, i'm wanting some help here if possible, for try solved this trouble of missing of methods in JNA.

I had fixed big part these erros but still missing some methods in JNA like i will show following point to point with comments.

```
package inject;

//////////////////// JNA-4.2.2 /////////////////////

import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Tlhelp32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;
import java.io.File;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Extracted from: https://github.com/warmuuh/AndroidCtx/tree/master/HotContext/src/luz/winapi

import inject.luz.winapi.constants.DwDesiredAccess;
import inject.luz.winapi.tools.Advapi32Tools;
import inject.luz.winapi.tools.Kernel32Tools;
import luz.winapi.api.exception.Kernel32Exception;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Inject {

    private static int GetPid(String proc){

         int id = 0;

         Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
         Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();          

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        try  {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {   

                if (Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile).equalsIgnoreCase(proc)) {

                    id = processEntry.th32ProcessID.intValue();

                }
             }
          }
    finally {
             kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }

     return id;
   }

  private static String findProcessByPID(int pid){

         String name = "";

         Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
         Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();          

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        try  {
            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) {   

                if (pid == processEntry.th32ProcessID.intValue()) {

                    name = processEntry.szExeFile.toString();
                }
             }
          }
    finally {
             kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }

     return name;
   }

   public static void inject(File dll, Integer pId) throws Kernel32Exception {

     if(null == dll || !dll.exists() || !dll.isFile() || !dll.getName().endsWith(".dll"))
            return;

    String p = findProcessByPID(pId);

    if(null == p) return;

    Kernel32 kernel  = Kernel32.INSTANCE;

    HMODULE kernel32Pointer  = kernel.GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");

                                      // Cannot find "GetProcAddress"
        Pointer loadLibraryAddress  = kernel.GetProcAddress(kernel32Pointer, "LoadLibraryA");

    HANDLE process  = null;

    DwDesiredAccess access  = new DwDesiredAccess();
        access.setPROCESS_ALL_ACCESS();

        try {
            Advapi32Tools.getInstance().enableDebugPrivilege(Kernel32Tools.getInstance().GetCurrentProcess());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

                            // Incompatible types "Pointer" and "HANDLE"  
        process = Kernel32Tools.getInstance().OpenProcess(access, false, pId);

        String path  = dll.getPath() + '\0';
        byte[] bytes  = path.getBytes();

        int pathLength  = bytes.length;

                                    // Cannot find "VirtualAllocEx"
        Pointer memoryDllPath  = kernel.VirtualAllocEx(process, null, pathLength, Kernel32Tools.MEM_COMMIT, Kernel32Tools.PAGE_READWRITE);

        Memory dllPathContent   = new Memory(pathLength);

        for(int i=0;i<pathLength;i++)
            dllPathContent.setByte(i, bytes[i]);

        IntByReference writeResult  = new IntByReference();

        boolean successWritting = kernel.WriteProcessMemory(process, memoryDllPath, dllPathContent, pathLength, writeResult);

        if(!successWritting) {

                kernel.CloseHandle(process);

            return;
        }

        IntByReference threadId   = new IntByReference();     

                // Pointer cannot be converted to "FOREIGN_THREAD_START_ROUTINE"
        Pointer thread   = kernel.CreateRemoteThread(process, null, 0, loadLibraryAddress, memoryDllPath, 0, threadId);

        boolean res   = false;

                        // Incompatible types "Pointer" and "HANDLE"             //Cannot find "WAIT_TIMEOUT"
            res = kernel.WaitForSingleObject(thread, Integer.MAX_VALUE) != Kernel32Tools.WAIT_TIMEOUT;

                // Cannot find "VirtualFreeEx" method                   // Cannot find "MEM_RELEASE" 
        kernel.VirtualFreeEx(process, memoryDllPath, pathLength, Kernel32Tools.MEM_RELEASE);

        kernel.CloseHandle(process);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

             System.out.println(GetPid("notepad.exe"));


  }
}
```

Thank in advance by any suggestion or help :-)

Comment: This could be a reasonable question if you listed the methods that are missing or otherwise giving you problems. Be specific. Expecting everyone to compile your code to find out what you mean is not well received on SO.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt, i edited above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA missing methods?  [It ain't so!](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#jna-is-missing-function-xxx-in-its-platform-library-mappings)

You just need to extend the library and add your own (and, ideally, also contribute the "missing" methods back to the JNA library so others can benefit.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/xderoche/ImYourFather/blob/master/api/core/src/main/java/fr/labri/reparenting/api/core/winapi/Kernel32Custom.java) of how someone has mapped GetProcAddress.

[Someone has mapped VirtualAllocEx here](https://github.com/pke/CopyTo/blob/master/com.sun.jna.examples.win32/src/com/sun/jna/examples/win32/Kernel32.java) (although they should properly have extended Kernel32 rather than copied it entirely and edited portions)

I couldn't find an example of VirtualFreeEx within the same 15 seconds I found the others... doesn't mean it's not out there but after writing the others you shouldn't have much trouble writing it as well.